How to check if there exist variables for which a function may be real?
I have a tough time in checking whether there exist any values of x and y (both real) for which the following pair of functions may be real
f1[x_, y_] = Sqrt[(-x)*(x + Sqrt[x*(x - 2*y)] - y)]; 
f2[x_, y_] = Sqrt[Sqrt[x^3*(x - 2*y)] + x*(-x + y)];

I checked for some values randomly and found both to be complex. I would like to know if there is a way to be absolutely sure about the nature (real of complex) of these functions.

Are x and y real or complex?

I assume you're ignoring f1[0, y] and f2[0, y] which are zero for any choice of y.

Assuming you mean $x,y \in \mathbb R$, you can use Reduce:
cond = Reduce[f1[x, y] ∈ Reals && f2[x, y] ∈ Reals, {x, y}, Reals]
(* (x < 0 && y == 0) || x == 0 *)

FullSimplify[{f1[x, 0], f2[x, 0]}, cond]
(* {0, 0} *)

Therefore, the only way for your functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ to be real is when they are both zero, and this hapens for either $x=0$ or $y=0 \wedge x<0$.

My wording was clumsy, indeed. I wanted to say that the only real values $f_1,f_2$ can obtain is zero.
